# How to make module variables that can be accessible in class and in each model instance?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, design-patterns, module

I can access to module `pluggins_list` method through e.g. `@page.plugins.pluggins_list`, but if I'm trying to get `Plugginable` methods or variables in `Plugin` model by e.g. `@page.page_elements.first.get_pluggin` I got nil or undefined. How to make module `pluggins` accessable outside and also that they can be available in each `Plugin` instance?

Edit, better example:

```
[3] pry(#<Plugin>)> plg = Plugin.new(name: "nutella")
=> #<Plugin id: nil, element_type: "Plugin", name: "nutella", page_id: nil>
[4] pry(#<Plugin>)> plg.get_pluggin
[5] pry(#<Plugin>)> plg.pluggins
=> nil
[6] pry(#<Plugin>)> pluggin_by_name(name)
NoMethodError: undefined method `find' for nil:NilClass
```

Current code:

```
module Plugginable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern
  attr_accessor :pluggins

  included do
    @pluggins = [{name: "dupa"},{name: "hello"}]
  end

  module ClassMethods
    def pluggins_list
      @pluggins
    end
  end

  def pluggin_by_name(name)
    @pluggins.find {|plg| plg.name === name.downcase }
  end

  module InstanceMethods
  end
end

class Plugin < PageElement
  include Plugginable

  def get_pluggin
    binding.pry
    # pluggin_by_name(name)
  end
end
```

Comment: Maybe (probably) `@page.page_elements.first` doesn't return `Plugin` instance? Show your error message. 
BTW `{name: 'dupa'}` - nice. :)

Comment: Checked, it is correct in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You try to call `pluggin_by_name`, which is class singleton method, on the instance (your `self` is an instance of `Plugin` in `pry` console). This should work:

```
Plugin.pluggin_by_name(name)
```

Also, this part:

```
included do
  @pluggins = [{name: "dupa"},{name: "hello"}]
end
```

makes no sense. You want your `@pluggins`, as far as I understand, as an instance variable of `Plugin`, but in this block `self` certainly isn't `Plugin` instance but, if I remember correctly, `Plugin` class. If you want `pluggins` attr reader to work, maybe you should set some kind of default value, like this:

```
module Plugginable
  attr_writer :pluggins
  def pluggins
    @pluggins ||= [{name: 'dupa'}, {name: 'hello'}]
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for tip. I moved `pluggin_by_name` outside `ClassMethods`, now it can be invoked, but `@pluggins` are sitll nil and it rise error, presented in updated question.

Comment: I accepted your answer, but I'm now confused how to access `pluggins` from `ClassMethods`, in `pluggins_list` there are nil. I have to invoke them by `@page.plugins.pluggins_list`.

Comment: Yes, because as far as I understand, you wanted `pluggins` to belong to particular `Plugin` instance, not entire class. So how can you know which instance's `pluggins` you want from class scope?

Comment: I see, I have predefined pluggins array that I want to list in selectbox during creating new page, next when page is displayed I want to pick right plugin by name from Plugginable and fill it with stored hash data.